# Improve update query SSJS block to report errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I've just managed to make a landing page where you can enter the target data extension, update type, and query definition of a query you want to run, press submit, and run it.

It uses the following code (a mix of ampscript and SSJS)

```
%%[
    var @target, @type, @definition
    set @target = RequestParameter("target")
    set @type = RequestParameter("type")
    set @definition = RequestParameter("definition")
]%%


<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("RunQuery");
var target = Variable.GetValue("@target");
var type = Variable.GetValue("@type");
var qdef = Variable.GetValue("@definition");
var status = qd.Update({
    Name : "RunQuery",
TargetUpdateType : (type),
TargetType : "DE",
Target : {
    Name : (target),
    CustomerKey : (target)
},
    QueryText : (qdef)
    });

qd.Perform();
</script>
Complete.
```

It works perfectly - you enter your query in free text in the previous page, then this block updates the query definition to it.

The only problem is, it won't tell you if anything goes wrong or the query couldn't run. For example I filled the query definition with nonsense, pressed submit, and still got the 'Complete' message.

My SSJS knowledge is limited - does anyone know how I can put some error handling on this to reject it if the querydef or target DE is invalid?

Comment: I believe you need to set the qd.Perform() to a var.  Something like `var performStatus = qd.Perform();`. This var should then contain the status info you want.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the variable `status` is capturing the result of the method `qd.Update()` say as either 'success' or 'failure'.  You can then replace the word 'complete' with the below code.  The below code displays 'Complete' or 'Error' based on the status.

```
%%=IIF(@status == 'success', 'Complete', 'Error')=%%
```

read as if the status is a success, display Complete else display Error.

Comment: Never mind, I got it! I'll have to set it with set value.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a try/catch block to catch any issues with the perform call itself.  Not sure there's a way to check for any query errors if it's been successfully "performed".

```
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");

    // or Attribute.GetValue('varname')
    var target = Request.GetQueryStringParameter('target');
    var type = Request.GetQueryStringParameter('type');
    var definition = Request.GetQueryStringParameter('definition');

    var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("RunQuery");

    try {

        var status = qd.Update({
            Name : "RunQuery",
            TargetUpdateType : (type),
            TargetType : "DE",
            Target : {
                Name : (target),
                CustomerKey : (target)
            },
            QueryText : (qdef)
        });
        qd.Perform();

    } catch (e) {
        Write("Error: " + Stringify(e));
        // or do whatever else 
    }

</script>
Complete.
```